# HTML List Item Number Displaced by Containing "float" Element

Tags: html, css

Below is the HTML code for two ordered list items. I need to insert an element with `float: left` into some of these list items. But this shifts the numbering to the right:

```css
.blob {
    float: left;
    width: 1cm;
    height: 5mm;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li><div class="blob"></div> Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

How can we avoid that? I prefer solutions without JavaScript.

**To be clear:** I want the numbers to be below each other and the red box left to the text of the second item.

**Update:** This issue only appears in Chrome.

Comment: Can you explain which effect you want to achieve? Where do you want to have the red div?

Comment: It is doing what it is supposed to do !

Comment: @esel: I updated my question.

Comment: @theV0ID It may be worth noting in your question that the issue only appears to effect Chrome. FF and IE appear to display correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `float`, try `display:inline-block` instead.

*Note: As mentioned by @HiddenHobbes in a comment*

> the [original] issue only appears to occur in Chrome.

```css
.blob {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1cm;
    height: 5mm;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li><div class="blob"></div> Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Correct me If I am wrong , both Op's and your output looks same ?

Comment: @n01ze You are both wrong and right! :) Paulie's suggestion does work, the reason why it may look the same is that the issue only appears to occur in Chrome.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Gosh :/ my bad again , I was checking in FF

Comment: My bad too...I didn't check FF either...apparently neither did the OP.

Comment: No worries @n01ze, it wasn't until I looked at yours and a few other comments that I realised the result was different between browsers.